# How do you get the path to the Laravel Storage folder?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store uploaded images to my Laravel-based web app in a subdirectory of the Laravel `storage` directory. It's the directory at the same hierarchy level as the 'application' and 'public' directories.

Is there a framework method for doing this? I've searched the docs but can't find one.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In Laravel 3, call [`path('storage')`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/3.0/paths.php#L124-L136).

In Laravel 4, use the [`storage_path()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L766-L769) helper function.

Answer (score 91):

For Laravel 5.x, use `$storage_path = storage_path()`.

From [the Laravel 5.0 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#paths):

> #### storage_path
>
> Get the fully qualified path to the `storage` directory.

Note also that, **for Laravel 5.1 and above**, [per the Laravel 5.1 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#paths):

> You may also use the `storage_path` function to generate a fully qualified path to a given file relative to the storage directory:
>
> ```
> $path = storage_path('app/file.txt');
> ```

Answer (score 37):

## For Laravel version >=5.1

### storage_path()

The `storage_path` function returns the fully qualified path to the storage directory:

```
$path = storage_path();
```

**You may also use the `storage_path` function to generate a fully qualified path to a given file relative to the storage directory:**

```
$app_path = storage_path('app');
$file_path = storage_path('app/file.txt');
```

**Source:** [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#paths)

Comment: For the record, the downvote on this answer is mine. I downvoted it because all the prose is copied and pasted from the docs, but is neither wrapped in quote marks or formatted as a block quotation, which is in violation of our [referencing policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). My apologies for only commenting to point this out now; I thought I had left a comment previously, but apparently not. Additionally, I think it would've been more useful to simply add the note about Laravel 5.1 as an edit to my answer (now made) than as a standalone answer in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

**Laravel 8.x <**

If the file in a default disk: /storage/app/public/file.jpg, then:

```
$path = Storage::path('file.jpg');
```

if the file in a different storage. Ex: /storage/app/storage-dir/sub-dir/file.txt

```
Storage::disk('storage-dir')->path('sub-dir/file.txt')
```

And the $path will be "/var/www/project1/storage/app/storage-dir/sub-dir/file.txt"

There are also `url()`

```
$path = Storage::disk('storage-dir')->url('sub-dir/file.txt');
```

This will returns the path like: `/storage/sub-dir/file.txt`

For the ealier Laravel versions:
`storage_path('app/file.txt');`

Answer (score 5):

use this artisan command for create  shortcut in public folder

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Than you will able to access posted img or file

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `storage_path();` function to get storage folder path.

`storage_path();  // Return path like: laravel_app\storage`

Suppose you want to save your logfile `mylog.log` inside Log folder of storage folder. You have to write something like

`storage_path() . '/LogFolder/mylog.log'`